# Is it possible to have multiple column-level named constraints in SQL? What is the syntax?

Tags: sql, postgresql, syntax, constraints, ddl

I can create multiple column-level constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(   
    bar int CHECK (bar >= 0) UNIQUE NOT NULL
);
```

Is it possible to name them separately, like so?

```
CREATE TABLE foo
(   
    bar int CONSTRAINT a CHECK (bar >= 0) CONSTRAINT b NOT NULL CONSTRAINT c UNIQUE
);
```

PostgreSQL `CREATE TABLE` syntax is given [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createtable.html), though I having trouble parsing it.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Ah I think I just got confused because the NOT NULL constraint doesn't use a name:

    insert into foo (bar) values(NULL);
    ERROR:  null value in column "bar" violates not-null constraint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the syntax you provided works just fine (at least in 9.3.9 which I have installed).